# How many transfer events are there in Ethereum?

Tags: erc-20, transfer, transferfrom

So I learnt that ERC20 tokens have `Transfer` and `TransferFrom` event. From my understanding `Transfer` event is when a transaction comes from an address to the smart contract instructing the transfer of some of its tokens to another address. `TransferFrom`, comes from an address that has been pre approved to transfer tokens from another address.

Here are my questions:

- What event is triggered when normal transfer of Eth from one account to another account occurs?
- What example are there on how to subscribe to these events using the JSON_RPC endpoints? Is subscribing to ERC20 token events different from subscribing to normal Ethereum transfer?
- How will same transactions look like using a library like ethers-rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC20 tokens are smart contracts that comply with the [EIP-20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20).

This standard states 2 different transfer functions: `transfer` and `transferFrom`, which work as you have defined:

- `transfer`

> Transfers `_value` amount of tokens to address `_to`, and MUST fire the `Transfer` event. The function SHOULD `throw` if the message caller’s account balance does not have enough tokens to spend.
> *Note* Transfers of 0 values MUST be treated as normal transfers and fire the `Transfer` event.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
```

- `transferFrom`

> Transfers `_value` amount of tokens from address `_from` to address `_to`, and MUST fire the `Transfer` event. The `transferFrom` method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to transfer tokens on your behalf.
> This can be used for example to allow a contract to transfer tokens on your behalf and/or to charge fees in sub-currencies. The function SHOULD `throw` unless the `_from` account has deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism.
> *Note* Transfers of 0 values MUST be treated as normal transfers and fire the `Transfer` event.

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
```

They both refer to the same event `Transfer`:

- `Transfer`

> MUST trigger when tokens are transferred, including zero value transfers.
> A token contract which creates new tokens SHOULD trigger a Transfer event with the `_from` address set to `0x0` when tokens are created.

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)
```

Finally, answering your questions:

- *What event is triggered when normal transfer of Eth from one account to another account occurs?*

There is no event emitted when an account transfers Ether to another account as events are accessible solely by declaring them in smart contracts and then calling them.

- *What example are there on how to subscribe to these events using the JSON_RPC endpoints? Is subscribing to ERC20 token events different from subscribing to normal Ethereum transfer?*

You can subscribe to ERC20 `Transfer` events using `ethers.js` as [documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events) shows:

```js
// This filter could also be generated with the Contract or
// Interface API. If address is not specified, any address
// matches and if topics is not specified, any log matches
filter = {
    address: "dai.tokens.ethers.eth",
    topics: [
        utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
    ]
}
provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {
    // Emitted whenever a DAI token transfer occurs
})
```

You cannot directly subscribe to Ether transfer transactions as they are potentially every single transaction.

- *How will same transactions look like using a library like ethers-rs*

You can find event examples in `ethers.js` [documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/concepts/events/):

```js
abi = [
  "event Transfer(address indexed src, address indexed dst, uint val)"
];

contract = new Contract(tokenAddress, abi, provider);

// List all token transfers *from* myAddress
contract.filters.Transfer(myAddress)
// {
//   address: '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F',
//   topics: [
//     '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
//     '0x0000000000000000000000008ba1f109551bd432803012645ac136ddd64dba72'
//   ]
// }
```

Comment: if no event is triggered with normal transaction, how do one listen to "transfer activities"?